# How can I switch order of 2 div using css only?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, flexbox

I'm wondering how can I change the order of those 2 divs for mobile users only using css (or js) only (PHP is not an option because I'm using full page caching). and that should happen for variable products only (I think the lower div has a different class name for variation product so I think it should not be a problem)

This is the page:
https://bonmedico.net/products/bandages-orthoses/stato/

And this is a screenshot showing the 2 divs I need to switch places: https://ibb.co/mMdYw9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With flexbox you can change the order of divs inside a wrapper div.
Using @media queries you can do that dependent on the screen size.
I made a simple code sample. You should be able to adapt it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

/* For Mobile - change the max-width to whatever you want */

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .wrapper>#firstDiv {
    order: 2;
  }
  .wrapper>#secondDiv {
    order: 1;
  }
}

/* For other and change the min-width here as well.  */

@media screen and (min-width: 540px) {
  .wrapper>#firstDiv {
    order: 1;
  }
  .wrapper>#secondDiv {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div id="firstDiv">
    This is usually first
  </div>

  <div id="secondDiv">
    This is usually second
  </div>
</div>
```